# Correlation Network Graphs in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, data-visualization

I have been searching for a package to produce a chart like the one below, but have been coming up short. Does anyone know a library which can produce something similar in R? The nodes of the graph are the variables in a data set and the thickness between the nodes are defined by the absolute values of their pairwise Pearson correlation. For visual simplicity, absolute weights below a certain threshold are not displayed. The node size is determined by a node’s number of connections. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in R with `ggnet2` function as described with examples [here](https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/). In `ggnet2` one *can* modify the colors, sizes and labels of both, nodes and their connections (though it *cannot* do curved edges, self-loops or hypergraphs). It should be relatively easy (especially if you are familiar with `ggplot2`).

If you need more interactivity (or are familiar with `vis.js`), you may be more interested in `visNetwork` suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without ggplot2, you can use the `igraph` package, with a complete tutorial here : http://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph